# python fabric perform actions from prompt on all servers

Tags: python, fabric

I have several servers on my my fab file,
and I want to have a function that will prompt me of what to do and than perform it on all servers.

```
def simple():
   actions = prompt('Type the actions: ')
   run(actions)
```

now when I do that I get:

```
[web1] Type the actions:
        bla bla bla

[web2] Type the actions:
        bla bla bla

[web3] Type the actions:
        bla bla bla
```

I want to type the "bla bla bla" only once and it will be performed on all servers,
is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if `simple()` here is a Fabric task, then this behaviour is expected, as you will have the `prompt()` call for every host on which the task is executed. I suppose, you use the `fab` command-line tool, and in the simplest case:

```
# fabfile.py

from fabric.api import run, env

env.hosts = ['host1', 'host2']

def simple(command=''):
    run(command)
```

And launch it as follows:

```
$ fab simple:'ls -la'
```

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to do something with prompts? as I have many "questions" and I want it to be easy to undestand

Comment: I'm not certain that you can do that directly without modifying the `fab` tool's code, but you can easily achieve that in a shell script. Here is a bash one-liner: `echo 'Type the actions: '; read actions; fab simple:'$actions' `